# How to save a numpy array in another numy array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to save a numpy array in a given location of another numpy array

```
import numpy as np
spotsAreaArray=np.zeros(30)
weatherConditions=np.zeros(30)

def saveInitialSpotId(spotId,spotArea,humidityReading,temperatureReading,lightReading):
    #Store initial area of the spot at the respective location of the spot id
    if spotsAreaArray[spotId] == 0:
        spotsAreaArray[spotId]=spotArea
        if weatherConditions[spotId] == 0:
            sensorReadings=np.array(humidityReading,temperatureReading,lightReading)
            weatherConditions[spotId]=sensorReadings
            print(weatherConditions)
    print(spotsAreaArray)

saveInitialSpotId(0,23,33,33,33)
saveInitialSpotId(0,25,55,55,55)
saveInitialSpotId(1,24,44,44,44)
saveInitialSpotId(1,99,99,99,99)
```

what I need to do is to,store the sensorReadings array values in given spotId location in weatherConditions array.But this isn't working.Please give me a guidance to achieve this?

Comment: Create a mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Answer (score 0):

`np.array` does not take 3 positional arguments. Making your readings a single list instead of a series of arguments will solve the issue.

```
sensorReadings=np.array([humidityReading,temperatureReading,lightReading])
```

And just to be on the safe side: your array initialization will also yield trouble, as you will run into:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Which can, for example, be solved by initializing your array as:

```
weatherConditions=np.zeros((30,3))
```